# How To Extract Recurring Array Values

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array $youtubeabout's dump;

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=310)
      0 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFFE6wa2VsYQAfhkMZCnLPQ' (length=56)
      1 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFFE6wa2VsYQAfhkMZCnLPQ' (length=56)
      2 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYBzff129L5OrVs6UUICW0g' (length=56)
      3 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYBzff129L5OrVs6UUICW0g' (length=56)
      4 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCz5jvb6SUgwDftN7zHfUDoQ' (length=56)
      5 => string 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCz5jvb6SUgwDftN7zHfUDoQ' (length=56)
```

It's small amount of my array;
As you can see some values recurring. 
I've tried to get them if they are recuring like that;

```
    $getthesearchpage = file_get_contents('goog.txt');
preg_match_all('/((http|https):\/\/|)(www.|)youtube\.com\/(channel\/|user\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,}/', $getthesearchpage, $youtubeabout);

$i = 0;
while ($youtubeabout[0][$i] != $youtubeabout[0][$i++]){

    print_r($youtubeabout[0]);
    $i++;
} 
`
```

What to do?

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: Totally blank. No error.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "get them if they are recurring" ?

Comment: Look at first and second line for example. I want them single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I understood your question, but if you want unique elements in your array, there is a PHP function for that: [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$getthesearchpage = file_get_contents('goog.txt');
preg_match_all('/((http|https):\/\/|)(www.|)youtube\.com\/(channel\/|user\/)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,}/', $getthesearchpage, $youtubeabout);

$youtubeabout[0] = array_unique($youtubeabout[0]);
var_dump($youtubeabout[0]); // print that
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(56) "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFFE6wa2VsYQAfhkMZCnLPQ"
  [2]=>
  string(56) "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYBzff129L5OrVs6UUICW0g"
  [4]=>
  string(56) "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCz5jvb6SUgwDftN7zHfUDoQ"
}
```

### Edit:

You can iterate over that array and delete that are more or less than 57 characters:

```
foreach ($youtubeabout[0] as $k => $v) {
    if (strlen($v)!=57)
        unset($youtubeabout[0][$k]);
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem. What if I want exact number charachters?
I mean if I want only 57 charactered elements?

Comment: exact number of characters on each link ?

Comment: I want only 57 charactered elements. Not more or less.

Comment: see Edit on my anwser